# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. Create a new .csv file. KeyError: 'Id'

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have a .csv file and I want split it beetwen two new files. I do it. It looks the same.

```
with open('/my/path/labels.csv', 'r') as inp, open('/my/path/labels_new.csv', 'w') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    writer.writerow(("Id", "age","name","Target"))
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        for i in image_list:
            if row[0] == i:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

But I get an error when I try use my new file in a program. 
    TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

image_fps.append(dir+'/'+row['Id']+'.dcm')

KeyError: 'Id'
```

What should I change in my code to create a 'good' .csv file?

Edit:

```
      7     for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
----> 8         image_fps.append(dir+'/'+row['Id']+'.dcm')
```

Comment: part of code, which is raising exception is not mentioned, please show where are you using "image_fps.append"

Comment: `row` is a list of strings. You need to index it with an integer value. Consider using `csv.DictReader`.

Answer (score 0):

During this line `image_fps.append(dir+'/'+row['Id']+'.dcm')` , as explained by martineau, row is a LIST and not a DataFrame (for example) where you can access the column using the column name.

Please try to rewrite it as `image_fps.append(dir+'/'+row[0]+'.dcm')`
where the zeroth index refers to the ID of that particular row.

Comment: Thanks but I need change a .csv file not only this line. Because I use a .csv a lot of times.